# Is $C[a,b]$ complete when given the norm $||f||:=\sup_{x\in [a,b]} \Big|\int_a^xf(t)dt \Big|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Is $C[a,b]$ complete when given the norm $||f||:=\sup_{x\in [a,b]} \Big|\int_a^xf(t)dt \Big|$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ denote $C([a,b])$ with your proposed norm, and let $Y$ denote $C([a,b])$ with the uniform norm.  Consider the map $T : X \to Y$ defined by $(Tf)(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$.  Then $T$ is an isometry.  If $X$ is complete, then its image $TX \subset Y$ is also complete, hence must be a closed subspace of $Y$.  But $TX$ consists precisely of the $C^1$ functions (satisfying $F(a)=0$), which are not closed in the uniform norm on $C([a,b])$.

Alternate proof: consider the identity map $I : Y \to X$.  Since $\|f\|_X \le (b-a) \|f\|_Y$, the map $I$ is continuous.  It is also bijective.  Clearly $Y$ is complete, so if $X$ were also complete, the open mapping theorem would say that $I^{-1}$ is continuous, meaning the $X$ and $Y$ norms are equivalent.  But this is clearly not true; consider for example a sequence $f_n$ with narrow bumps of height 1.  They converge to 0 in the $X$ norm but not in the $Y$ norm.

Comment: The first proof is quite elegant.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge : I know that $C^1[a,b]$ is not complete ; but why is $\{f\in C^1[a,b] :f(a)=0\}$ not complete w.r.t. sup norm ( or equivalently not closed in $C[a,b]$ under sup norm ) ?

Comment: @user228169: Choose a continuous function which is not $C^1$ (something like $|x|$ would do) and construct a sequence of $C^1$ functions which converge to it uniformly.  Or, to be lazier, invoke the Weierstrass approximation theorem to assert the existence of such a sequence.

Comment: @NateEldredge : But can we always gurantee that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ satisfies $f_n(a)=0$ ?

Comment: @user228169: If the sequence converges uniformly to an appropriate function, you will have $f_n(a)$ converging to 0.  So consider the sequence $g_n(x) = f_n(x) - f_n(a)$ which has $g_n(a)=0$ and converges uniformly to the same limit.